# SaaS/Multitenant maven project using Spring, Hibernate/Athena and MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, hibernate, maven, multi-tenant

I am working on a Multitenant application for a start-up and based on the requirement I am asked to use Spring, Hibernate/Athena and MongoDB on cloud (AWS). I have been researching on the above topics since last couple of weeks and have experience on working with Spring, Hibernate and Relational DBs. I know there are some docs on using spring-and-hibernate-with-mongodb. I think that Athena FW was specifically designed for multi-tenant application and there are sample code to get quickly started with it. But, Hibernate seems to be more popular and hence will have support on how to use it with MongoDB and Spring. I want to know which FW I should go with Hibernate or Athena for multi-tennant app. Is there some project set-up guideline using above technologies.

Comment: Hibernate has [in-built multi-tenancy support](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html); MongoDB does not. You can use [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) with Hibernate as the JPA provider to have multi-tenancy support in your application. MongoDB can then be added as the second data-store using [Spring Data MongoDB](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/) with cross-store support. You can also use the entire stack with [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

Comment: @manish as suggested I was working on Spring Data MongoDB with Spring MVC. Will this be self sufficient for multi-tenant application. Can you suggest some good tutorials where both Spring Data JPA and Spring Data MongoDB is used preferably (not necessarily) with Spring MVC

Comment: MongoDB does not have multi-tenant support so it is something you will have to build on your own.  Documentation on cross-store support is included in the [official Spring Data MongoDB documents](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.cross.store).